# Fillable Word form to Excel and save to OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want data in a fillable Word form to be automatically updated in one Excel file.
Both files need to be saved but the Excel file gives a quick overview of the information.

I would like to retrieve Word files from a folder to update the Excel file.

I've seen a couple of videos that give an example but none seem to work.

```vb
Sub getWordFormData()
    Dim wdApp As Object, myDoc As Object
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    myFolder = "/Users/tomlecomte/Desktop/testproces wego/test/test excel"

    If Len(Dir(myFolder)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox myFolder & vbCrLf & "Not Found", vbInformation, "Cancelled - getWordFormData"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Clear
        With .Range("A1:D1")
            .Value = Array("Datum", "Kenteken", "Merk", "Model")
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        
        strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)

        i = 1
        While strFile <> ""
            i = i + 1

            Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=myFolder & "\" & strFile, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

            .Cells(i, 1).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Datum").Item(1).Range.Text
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Kenteken").Item(1).Range.Text
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Merk").Item(1).Range.Text
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Model").Item(1).Checked

            myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
            strFile = Dir()
        Wend
        wdApp.Quit

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Sometimes the code seems to work but then my Excel file turns completely white.

The code has worked in the past but then my Excel screen turns white.

Comment: Are you sure you need `.Cells.Clear`?

Comment: `myFolder = "/Users/tomlecomte/Desktop/testproces wego/test/test excel"
` with a forward slash combined with a backslash `strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)` works ? curious question